# Graphviz language from jsp view Dynamic

Tags: java, graphviz

I have some roles and each roles have users.

[image]

So my problem is according to the no. of roles and no. of users selected i have to create a graph using graphviz. 
Graphviz language is like (A -> B;)(B -> C;)(B -> D;)(C -> E;)(D -> E;)(E -> F)

So i have to create a graph language according to no of roles i have and no. of users i selected...

The incoming string is like = (1CS_3Admin_1BOD_2SH_1Others).
And the graph for this language myst be like this:-

[image]

---

marapet This is what i am doing.

My language is like 1CS_3Admin_1BOD_2SH_1Others Where 1,3,1,2 is the no of users selected e.g 1CS means one user for CS role. Now i split them with '_' as delimiter . Now i get a string array . So the real problem is to make a language from this string array values. 
Here 'name' is the string i am getting:-

```
Graphviz gv = new Graphviz();
          gv.addln(gv.start_graph());
          gv.addln("Start;");

          if(name.startsWith("_"));
            name=name.substring(1);

          String[] str=null;

          if(name.contains("_"))
              str = name.split("_");

          int sPreviousRepeat=0;
          String sPrevious="";
          int sCurrRepeat=0;
          String sCurr="";

          String finalInst="Start -> ";

        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
             sCurrRepeat=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str[i].charAt(0)));
             sCurr=str[i].substring(1);
             if(i!=0){
                 sPreviousRepeat = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str[i-1].charAt(0)));
                 sPrevious = str[i-1].substring(1);
             }

             if(sCurrRepeat==1){
                 if(i==0)
                     finalInst=finalInst+sCurr+";";
                 else
                     finalInst=finalInst + sPrevious+" -> "+sCurr+";";
             }
             else{
                 for(int j=0;j<sCurrRepeat;j++){

                    //cant figure out????? 

                 }

             }

         }
```

Comment: Though tempted to +1 because of the local image path, you should upload those images and reference them with an url accessible to other stackoverflow users. Especially because that may helps us understand what exactly your question is.

Comment: actually my reputation score is 10 thats y i am not able to upload images. to upload images u need 10+ reputation

Comment: Just upload them directly to http://imgur.com/ and use the link

Comment: my problem is how to create a java program which read the string and create language for graphviz.

Comment: What's the actual question, how to take what's coming from the JSP and turn it into DOT? Not sure what that string actually contains, either.

Comment: Ok for the pictures - I actually see actions, roles and users. Still not sure what exactly the question is (teh codez?)

Comment: Suppose i choose some roles and users , so according to that i get a string(like 1CS_3Admin_1BOD_2SH_1Others,  here 1,3,1,2 is the number of users selected) in a java class. So according to this string i have to create a graph using graphviz. Now the problem is to generatre the graph , i have to create language for graphviz . How can i generate graph using string. I am not able to make a program for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd break down the problem:

1. Parse the input string into a data structure representing n ordered pairs of *role* and *number of users*
2. Creating the syntax of the graph (graphviz dot) from the data structure in #1
3. Transform the graphviz syntax into an actual image

You'll need to learn the following:

- Graphviz syntax
- Making a simple Java command line program
- Parsing and manipulating strings in Java (split etc.)
- Invoking an executable from java (dot.exe)

Comment: I know all the things u specify , but i am not able to create a program which convert the string into Graphviz syntax.

Comment: If you know how to make a command line java programm, and you know how to manipulate string in Java, and you know the graphviz syntax, but you don't know how to put it together, you have to be more specific and tell us where exactly you are having problems. Start with the first problem: Do you have a java command line program which compiles ("hello world")? Can you pass parameters (the input string) to it? Can you parse the input string? Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think i make it.

```
          if(name.contains("_"))
          str = name.split("_");

      int sPreviousRepeat=0;
      String sPrevious="";
      int sCurrRepeat=0;
      String sCurr="";

      String finalInst="Start -> ";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
         sCurrRepeat=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str[i].charAt(0)));
         sCurr=str[i].substring(1);
         if(i!=0){
             sPreviousRepeat = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str[i-1].charAt(0)));
             sPrevious = str[i-1].substring(1);
         }

         if(sCurrRepeat==1){
             if(i==0)
                 finalInst=finalInst+sCurr+";";
             else if(sPreviousRepeat>1){
                 for(int j=0;j<sPreviousRepeat;j++)
                     finalInst=finalInst + sPrevious+(j+1)+" -> "+sCurr+";";
             }
             else
                 finalInst=finalInst + sPrevious+" -> "+sCurr+";";
         }
         else{
             for(int j=0;j<sCurrRepeat;j++){
                 finalInst=finalInst + sPrevious+" -> "+sCurr+(j+1)+";";                                     
             }

         }

     }
```

Comment: I recommend separating the parsing of the input from the creation of the graphviz code.